# How to write a query in mysql on DAY?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Trying to write a query which will give me all "group by month" dates data.
In database date saved in Date format but i want to write a query which will give all "**Monday**" data from the database

Please Help

Answer (score 1):

Its return `monday` from your table dates
Try This

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE DAYOFWEEK(date_column) = 2
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE DAYNAME(date_column) = 'Monday';
```

Comment: @Strawberry you are right. i did't read carefully i remove or change this query

Comment: @PathikVejani 2 for monday (Returns the weekday index for date (1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, …, 7 = Saturday). copy from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek

Comment: @PathikVejani no problem.. :)

Comment: @PathikVejani why you remove your comment ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is query which gives **Monday** data:

```
SELECT *, DAYNAME(date) as Dayname FROM `tbl_name` WHERE WEEKDAY(date) = 0
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6649e/3)

Find `WEEKDAY` information from [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-weekday-function.php).